# Magento 2.2 - Product always in stock?

Tags: product, magento2.2, stock, manage-stock

I was wondering whether anyone could please advise how I can have a certain product that would always be in stock? I can see that you can set this from the config, however this applies to all products where I only need 1 product to always be in stock.

I've tried to change the option for the product to be in stock. But saving the product changes the product to be out of stock since the quantity is set to 0, however we do not want to set a quantity since we do not manage stock for the product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you must check the type of products magento have like down-loadable , virtual and etc .... withot changing at code level may be you achieve this just by changing the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cat change in the product level (admin) on `Advanced Inventory ->  Manage Stock` is must **No**

Chec [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJ1prMCJWqWAFYofKhwUoLdN1LsdL2DG/view).

Comment: Thank you :) Was struggling to find it since I had a module installed that removed the advanced inventory link on the product page but the video was very helpful.